# A substitution for Rive to use with kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, animation, rive

I was using `Rive` to make animation for my `flutter` project, But now I'm wondering if there is a good substitution for `Rive` to use with `kotlin` (or something similar to that) in native android programming so i would be able to use awesome animations in native android too?

Answer (score 2):

Doing a bit of searching I found that Rive has an integration with Android.

I don't know if it will be useful to you but I will still share the links.

https://help.rive.app/runtimes/overview/android
https://github.com/rive-app/rive-android

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32741656)

Answer (score 1):

For native android animations you can use:

- Lottie from airbnb -> https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android
- MotionLayout from google -> https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples
- Android Studio includes a visual design editor for the MotionLayout -> https://developer.android.com/studio/write/motion-editor